# How does an induction motor start when it has no capacitor or inductor?

Tags: motor, induction-motor

The photo below shows a bench grinder.  If you look carefully, there are only two wires for the main winding.  There's no capacitor or inductor.  I also verified this using the parts diagram.

I was under the impression that a single phase induction motor cannot start on its own without a capacitor or inductor connected to a secondary winding.[image: Induction motor]

My only guess is that this motor is a shaded pole motor, but I was under the impression that they are too under powered for this application.

Comment: Lots of 1/4-HP shaded pole motors. How many nameplate HP is this one? Looks like a shading bar visible too.

Comment: A shaded pole motor has problems starting under load. You don't start a bench grinder under load.

Comment: Yeah. Does a grinding wheel count as load?  I guess it probably has enough angular momentum to help it start.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This grinder is a JC penny vintage and no name plate came with it.   It was made here in the US back in the 1970s. Can you believe JC Penny sold stuff like this?  I thought they only sold clothing and homewares.

Comment: @user148298 Sears actually once sold lathes. People don't make metal stuff at home like they used to. See the old 1960s Popular Mechanics for what an ordinary Joe sixpack could do on the weekend.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Don't worry, should society suddenly collapse and practical skills be in demand, we'll have no shortage of people who can switch LEDs on and off.

Comment: @user148298: my bench grinder has no problem to speed it up within two seconds or so, so the dynamic load coming from it seems negligible. As soon the thing runs at contant speed it isn't load any more. This is different from a real load coming from grinding a paring chisel. That one takes power from the wheel and transforms it into heat (and acceleration of iron bits of course.)

Comment: I it must be a shaded pole motor There is no sign of an auxiliary winding and there is something that looks like a shading bar. The grinding wheel doesn't count as load nor does the angular momentum help to start. F=MA says that no matter how small the force, there will be acceleration. The momentum will determine how long it takes for the wheel to get up to speed. As long as there is enough torque to overcome bearing friction and turn the fan, it will get up to speed. The motor torque will increase as speed increases until it reaches a peak at 3/4 speed or so.

Comment: +1, but having too much angular momentum will make the rotor heat up because of high losses at low speeds and may trip a temperature fuse.

Comment: Yes. High losses when it starts plus speed reductions and high losses when load is applied. The motor is inefficient, but it has a fan that is almost as big as the motor.

Comment: I agree with Charles & Spehro. That lump of copper sitting between the windings make me think its a shaded-pole motor. Is there a matching piece showing on the other side of the motor (bottom of your image where we can't see)?

Comment: Yup it's a shaded pole. This was my initial guess, but as I said before, I didn't know they made them so largel Most of the ones I've seen are tiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks more like the old shaded Pole, with low starting torque that peaks before max RPM. (No old jokes please.)

Comment: I don't see a commutator at the OP's motor.

Comment: @Janka the heavy copper tab is actually the edge of a heavy copper ring.  It's off center, producing a phase-delayed field through the iron in the center of the shorting ring.  That gives a weak rotary field for starting torque.  Look up "shaded-pole motor," an induction motor invented in the 1930s.  (It appears that the copper ring is a "U" shape, inserted into two holes, then a copper segment welded across the tips of the "U."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaded-pole_motor

Comment: @wbeaty: Please see my comments on the question.